# SVG - animate/move dots along path

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm looking for a way to move dots along existing path in order to get animation that looks like this:
[image]

I was thinking about working with dasharray but wasn't able to get this exact behavior.

Here is an example of something I tried, but as you can see it doesn't really work:

```css
path.link {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
  stroke: black;
}
path.link-anim {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  animation: link-anim 5s linear infinite;
}
path.red {
  stroke: red;
}
path.blue {
  stroke: blue;
}
path.green {
  stroke: green;
}
path.pink {
  stroke: pink;
}
@keyframes link-anim {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 5 5 100%;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
        stroke-dasharray: 100% 5 5;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg width="450" height="450">
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M10,10L100,10"></path>
    <path class="link-anim red" d="M10,10L100,10"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M50,50L200,50"></path>
    <path class="link-anim blue" d="M50,50L200,50"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M75,75L75,200"></path>
    <path class="link-anim green" d="M75,75L75,200"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M85,85L450,450"></path>
    <path class="link-anim pink" d="M85,85L450,450"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

> Note - the angle of the line is not something I care about. I should have written this from the start. What I need is the 3 dots to move forward (and only those 3 dots).

Comment: Does it has to be using an SVG?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I need an SVG solution. If you have some other idea I'll be happy to hear/see, but I'm not sure I'll be able to use them.

Comment: Here is a demo using a div and pseudo elements: https://jsfiddle.net/kvkwaxs3/

Comment: @LGSon interesting! The problem is with the translateX, because the path is not always 90%/180% (well, mostly is different angel). Do you think that there is a solution for that?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/kvkwaxs3/1/

Comment: Since I'm using the SVG I can't change the deg of the path (it already has it's angle based on the start/end position).

Comment: Since I don't have the full picture, I can't suggest anything more at this point. Am also sure it is possible to do this with pure SVG, so be patient and some clever one will pass by and post one :)

Comment: @LGSon I added a new path with 45% deg to the SVG so it will be more clear

Comment: I took the time to learn some more about SVG :)  ... Let me know if what I posted is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply duplicate your paths, and set the stroke dash-array of the top one to only contain the 3 dots you need.

Then you can animate the dashoffset property of these top paths.

Note that it's not really modular, the dashoffset, dash-array and `steps()` timing function need to be calculated according to the path length.

```css
path, circle {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: transparent;
}

.bg {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 4 12;
}

.move {
  stroke: red;
  animation: link-anim 3s infinite steps(21);
  stroke-dasharray: 4 12 4 12 4 300;
}

@keyframes link-anim {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 368;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 32;
  }
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="330">
  <defs>
  <path id="v_path" d="M30,20V288"/>
  <path id="h_path" d="M30,20H358"/>
  <path id="d_path" d="M30,20L228 228"/>
  <circle id="c_path" cx="150" cy="150" r="53.4"/>
  </defs>
    <use class="bg" xlink:href="#v_path"/>
    <use class="move" xlink:href="#v_path"/>

    <use class="bg" xlink:href="#h_path"/>
    <use class="move" xlink:href="#h_path"/>

    <use class="bg" xlink:href="#d_path"/>
    <use class="move" xlink:href="#d_path"/>

    <use class="bg" xlink:href="#c_path"/>
    <use class="move" xlink:href="#c_path"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Will it work with all 4 paths in the example? I'm afraid because of the translateY it will work only on vertical paths.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, this solution is the closest to what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

I have made an Path animation with javascript (also running on IE) You can also
animate your points in this way.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Nürburgring Animation</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="publisher" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="copyright" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="description" content="Auf dieser Seite wird eine kleine Animation des Nürburgrings um Adenau dargestellt. Die Animation wurde komplett in Javascript und SVG erstellt.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="SVG, Animation, Webdesign, Adenau, Nürburgring, Eifel, Frank, Wisniewski, Programmierung, Grafik, Gestaltung, Kunst">
    <meta name="page-topic" content="Forschung Technik">
    <meta name="page-type" content="Karte Plan">
    <meta name="audience" content="Alle, Erwachsene, Fans"><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="DC.Creator" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="DC.Publisher" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="DC.Rights" content="Frank Wisniewski">
    <meta name="DC.Description" content="Auf dieser Seite wird eine kleine Animation des Nürburgrings um Adenau dargestellt. Die Animation wurde komplett in Javascript und SVG rtstellt.">
    <meta name="DC.Language" content="de">

    
    <style>
      body{font-family:"Calibri", "Helvetica", sans-serif;}
      .content{width:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
      #svgG{width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
      svg{width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;}
      h1,p{text-align:center;}
      p{font-size:8px;}
      .p10{font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;}
    </style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
    <div id="svgG"></div>
    <hr>
    <p>(c) Frank Wisniewski<br>Lohmühlenstraße 2</br>53518 Adenau</p>
    
    </div>
  <script>    
  /* Programm und Grafiken sind geistiges Eigentum von Frank Wisniewski, Lohmühlenstraße 2, 53518 Adenau und dürfen ohne Genehemigung nicht genutzt werden */

      var carCount = 8;
      var i;
      var colors = ["Black", "Navy", "Blue", "BlueViolet", "CornFlowerBlue","Red", "LimeGreen", "IndianRed", "Sienna"];
      var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
      var _create = function (type){return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);}
      var _set = function (el,par){for (key in par) {el.setAttribute(key.replace('X','-'),par[key]);}svg.appendChild(el);}
      with(svg){ 
        setAttribute('width', '250');
        setAttribute('height', '250');
        setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 250 250"); 
        setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
      } 
      svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
      svgG.appendChild(svg);
      var adenaubullet = _create("circle");
      _set(adenaubullet,{r:7,fill:'#f00',stroke:'#f00',cx:110,cy:8,strokeXwidth:1});
      var pfad = _create("path");
      pfad.setAttribute("d","M23.748,97.732c-4.235-2.956-3.875-3.774,0.149-6.424c4.415-2.912,9.246-4.657,13.445-7.991c3.775-2.997,6.616-6.559,8.157-11.154c0.658-1.969,0.469-3.708,0.928-5.656c0.49-2.073,2.818-3.084,2.289-5.231c-1.943-7.859,12.718-12.905,15.122-20.157c3.09-9.145-16.734-9.687-5.879-15.675c3.809-2.103,3.375-6.84,6.656-9.057c4.651-3.144,8.367,1.576,11.515,4.158c3.215,2.642,3.816-0.669,7.024-1.456c3.189-0.786,10.073,3.112,11.988-0.465c1.826-3.412,1.65-7.33,6.191-8.478c4.341-1.098,8.877-0.364,12.739-3.081c1.894-1.331,6.225-6.532,8.439-2.986c2.437,3.904-0.348,10.177,0.854,14.706c2.772,10.454,17.172,9.7,25.21,10.781c9.04,1.215,17.95,12.277,26.751,6.006c3.794-2.695,4.927-5.525,10.095-6.125c1.264-0.15,7.907-1.917,7.61,0.729c-0.316,2.853-6.305,5.333-8.338,6.711c-4.479,3.022-0.753,6.298,1.884,2.81c3.211-4.251,8.561-3.146,12.597-5.729c3.836-2.448,4.706-5.857,5.413-9.774c1.985-10.859,17.365-0.166,21.786,3.753c4.462,3.959,0.835,6.313,1.039,10.839c0.191,3.879,3.526,1.893,5.27,4.377c1.404,1.99,0.811,7.445-1.462,8.753c-3.792,2.168-6.586-2.64-9.273,2.805c-1.183,2.4-3.285,4.19-3.92,6.858c-0.735,3.091,1.969,7.785-0.122,10.477c-1.086,0.723-2.258,1.257-3.517,1.6c-1.907,1.228-3.592,3.089-5.258,4.608c-2.656,2.422-4.04,5.798-6.476,8.439c-3.986,4.336-10.271,6.805-16.063,7.526c-1.563,0.396-3.123,0.396-4.681,0c-2.271-0.944-1.521-3.241-4.827-2.771c-2.364,0.319-6.657,3.103-4.31,5.873c3.164,3.744,14.496,4.718,10.232,11.852c-4.087,6.844-13.375,9.795-19.857,13.7c-7.564,4.557-15.104,9.15-22.606,13.8c-7.321,4.53-16.081,8.639-22.572,14.298c-4.59,4.036-7.287,12.104-12.4,15.145c-2.264,1.35-1.265,4.361-4.132,5.722c-2.816,1.335-5.621-0.041-7.605-2.184c-0.949-1.027-2.493-4.413-4.188-2.536c-2.399,2.652-5.102,5.234-8.833,5.743c-3.432,0.466-6.206-1.944-9.507-1.572c-3.674,0.413-5.729-0.104-7.561-3.373c-1.255-2.242-3.559-3.075-5.613-4.396c-3.346-2.152-5.549-4.272-8.34-7.002c-5.066-4.96-13.847-9.133-14.34-17.222c-0.215-3.656,2.038-7.426,2.341-11.079c0.397-4.697-0.287-9.311-1.945-13.715c-1.431-3.801-3.489-7.284-4.994-11.039C29.209,99.368,26.926,99.928,23.748,97.732"); 
      _set(pfad,{fill:'none',stroke:'#666',strokeXwidth:6});
      var bordstein=pfad.cloneNode(true);
      _set(bordstein,{stroke:'#ddd',strokeXwidth:4});
      var grandprix = _create("path");
      grandprix.setAttribute("d","M32.246,245.125c-2.99-2.644,4.779-6.693,6.57-8.077c3.212-2.479,6.842-4.163,5.87-8.961c-0.891-4.404,1.944-8.48,3.929-12.302c1.225-2.359,2.457-4.719,3.468-7.177c1.085-2.64,0.846-3.498-1.781-4.92c-2.916-1.579-8.019-3.264-4.406-7.271c3.643-4.035,7.452-7.957,11.752-11.297c3.277-2.547,7.475-2.651,11.457-3.249c1.722-0.26,13.399-0.733,13.39-2.918c-0.015-3.294,6.497-2.777,8.654-3.153c1.517-0.266,5.267-1.056,5.688,1.308c0.445,2.497-1.268,3.257-2.928,4.664c-7.362,6.223-15.047,12.292-22.803,18.019c-0.534,0.395-8.754,5.805-8.457,3.525c0.423-3.213,5.225-8.695,1.275-11.084c-2.188-1.332-4.133-0.486-6.367,0.376c-1.574,0.607-5.299,1.734-6.084,3.411c-0.74,1.58,0.625,3.774,2.29,3.882c1.022,0.069,3.515-1.991,3.427,0.323c-0.094,2.511,0.521,5.18-0.138,7.646c-0.792,2.955-2.661,5.646-4.08,8.322c-0.9,1.696-3.023,4.913-2.296,7.02c0.89,2.563,4.673,2.549,5.777,4.88c1.078,2.279-4.431,3.46-5.976,4.184c-2.971,1.387-5.743,2.851-8.27,4.98c-1.822,1.534-3.684,3.438-5.079,5.381C35.841,244.419,34.963,247.523,32.246,245.125");
      _set(grandprix,{fill:'none', stroke:'#000', strokeXwidth:4});
      var grandprixbordstein=grandprix.cloneNode(true);
      _set(grandprixbordstein,{stroke:'#f00',strokeXwidth:3});
      var myText=_create("text");
      with (myText){
        setAttribute("font-family", "Arial, sans-serif");
        setAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
        setAttribute("font-style", "italic");
        setAttribute("text-anchor", "middle");
      }
      var myTextNode = document.createTextNode("");
      myText.appendChild(myTextNode);
      var nordschleife=myText.cloneNode(true);
      _set(nordschleife,{x:120,y:77,fontXsize:16});
      nordschleife.textContent="NORDSCHLEIFE";
      var grandprixtext=nordschleife.cloneNode(true);
      _set(grandprixtext,{x:110,y:220,fontXsize:16});
      grandprixtext.textContent="GRAND-PRIX";
      var grandprixtext1=nordschleife.cloneNode(true);
      _set(grandprixtext1,{x:110,y:240,fontXsize:16});
       grandprixtext1.textContent="STRECKE";
      var adenautext=nordschleife.cloneNode(true);
      _set(adenautext,{x:165,y:14,fontXsize:16});
      adenautext.textContent="ADENAU";
      var roundSquare=[];
      var mySquare=_create("rect");
      var roundBullet=[];
      var roundBulletText=[];
      for (i=1;i <= carCount;i++){
        
        roundBullet[i]=adenaubullet.cloneNode(true);
        _set(roundBullet[i],{r:5,strokeXwidth:0,fill:colors[i],stroke:colors[i],cx:180,cy:120+i*5*3});
        
        roundSquare[i]=mySquare.cloneNode(true);
        _set(roundSquare[i],{x:203,y:113+i*5*3,fill:'#ddd',stroke:'none',height:13,width:30});
        
        roundBulletText[i]=adenautext.cloneNode(true);
        _set(roundBulletText[i],{x:210,y:125+i*5*3,fontXsize:14,fontXstyle:'normal'});
        roundBulletText[i].textContent="0";
      }
      var lapsText=nordschleife.cloneNode(true);
      _set(lapsText,{x:217,y:122,fontXsize:14,fontXstyle:'normal'});
      lapsText.textContent="LAPS";
      var cars = [];
      var step=[];
      var laps=[];
      var len = pfad.getTotalLength();
      var speed = 1.5;
      var pos = [];
      var pt;
      var repeater;
      var lapPos = [];
      var carProto = _create("circle");
      with (carProto){
        setAttribute("r", 3);
        setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
      }
      for(i = 1; i <= carCount; i++){
        cars[i]=carProto.cloneNode(true);
        pos[i]=i*5+750;
        laps[i]=0;
        lapPos[i]=750;
        pt=pfad.getPointAtLength(len/1000*pos[i])
        _set(cars[i],{cx:pt.x,cy:pt.y,stroke:colors[i],fill:colors[i]});
        step[i]=speed+Math.random()/1;
      }
      var animate=function(){
        for(i = 1; i <= carCount; i++){
          pos[i]+=step[i];
          lapPos[i]+=step[i];
          if(pos[i]>1000){
            pos[i]=1;
            step[i]=speed+Math.random()/2;  
          }
          if (lapPos[i]>1750){
            lapPos[i]=750;
            laps[i]++;
            roundBulletText[i].textContent=laps[i];
          }
          pt=pfad.getPointAtLength(len/1000*pos[i])
          cars[i].setAttribute("cx", pt.x);
          cars[i].setAttribute("cy", pt.y);
        }
        //repeater = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        repeater = setTimeout(animate,1000/60);
      }
      animate();

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: got it much out of it Thank you, But what do 1750 (lapPos) and 750 do(means why it is static and still everything working word fine!! do it has to do with step)? but of explanation will help a lot :). 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I added 2 more variants (sample 3, 4), using your original SVG and `<animationTransform>`.

---

*Note 1, using `<animationTransform>` have less browser support*

*Note 2, since [Chrome favor CSS/Web animations over SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL), the future of SMIL might be somewhat unpredictable, so I would recommend to wait using it until its future is more secured.*

---

Sample 1/2 benefit from rotating the element itself, which makes it much simpler when it comes to define each step, while with sample 3, one need to recalculate those for every angled used.

With sample 4 I made the 3 dots a solid line instead, using same color as the background, to show how that looks and its simpler code compared with sample 3.

Sample 1, using SVG

```css
svg {
  background: black;
}
svg + svg {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
line.nr2 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: anim 2s steps(18) infinite;
}
@keyframes anim {
  0%   { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(500%); }
}
```

```html
<svg width="320px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 320 20">
    <line class="nr1" x1="10" x2="320" y1="10" y2="10" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 20"/>
    <line class="nr2" x1="10" x2="73" y1="10" y2="10" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 20"/>
</svg>

<svg width="320px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 320 20">
    <line class="nr1" x1="10" x2="320" y1="10" y2="10" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 20"/>
    <line class="nr2" x1="10" x2="73" y1="10" y2="10" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 20"/>
</svg>
```

---

Sample 2, using pseudo element

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 55px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size:16px;
}
div + div {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

div::before {
  content: '• • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • •';
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px; 
}
div::after {
  content: '• • •';
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 2px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: anim 2s steps(24) infinite;  
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%   { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(190px); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div></div>
```

---

Sample 3, 4

```css
path.link {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
  stroke: black;
}
path.red {
  stroke: red;
}
path.white {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M3,3L150,150"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path id="path2" class="link anim red" d="M-18,-18L3,3">
      <animateTransform 
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        values="0 0;7 7;14 14;21 21;28 28;35 35;42 42;50 50;57 57;
                64 64;71 71;78 78;85 85;92 92;99 99;106 106;113 113;
                120 120;127 127;134 134;141 141;148 148;155 155"
        calcMode="discrete"
        begin="0s"
        dur="3s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="150" height="150">
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M3,3L150,150"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path id="path2" class="link anim white" d="M-18,-18L3,3">
      <animateTransform 
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="250 250"
        begin="0s"
        dur="3s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've got a doubt, but IIRC for each value of `values` atribute - 1 there should be an keyTime value. `values` will make `from` and `to` useless. I guess it's why your SMIL do not work on my FF. Also SMIL is not supported in IE and requires an js shim for these browsers (and thus impossible to link in CSS, though OP didn't told that in needs IE support.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks....that's why I have the first 2 samples, but will make a comment about this

Comment: But you should be able to make it work on FF by fixing this values incorrect declaration. FF does support most of SMIL.

Comment: @Kaiido I read up some more on SMIL today, an hour ago, at [guide-svg-animations-smil](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/), and was expecting that would at least be compliant with the browsers that actually support SMIL...but now, after google some more, it seems SMIL has a somewhat insecure future ?

Comment: I only did a really fast reading of code blocks in this article, but every one I saw using `values` also had `keyTimes`

Comment: @Kaiido Check this sample, 3:rd animation, from which I took the code: https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/EzAju

Comment: @Kaiido I also remove the `from`/`to` but it still doesn't work in FF...but based on that Chrome favor CSS/Web animations and actually deprecated SMIL (later suspended that, but still), I would recommend to wait using SMIL until its future is more secured

Comment: Finally got back to my computer (I was on my phone before) and the problem is actually in your `d` declaration. I guess FF doesn't like that everything is splitted with `,` these should be used only to separate between same commands points, the split between two commands is already induced in the command letter : `M-18-18L3,3`  will make it work on FF too.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much for spotting that, updated...must have made that mistake when swapping back and forth between values trying to get correct position for those 3 dots

Comment: @LGSon thanks for your solutions! The `animateTransform` is great, but currently not supported enough and your other solutions are based on the angle of the path/line/div so I decided to go with Kaiido's solution. You got my vote here :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a rotate in your path. I also changed some of your settings so you can see the line work:

https://jsfiddle.net/yex8n8nj/

```
<div>
<svg>
  <g>
    <path class="link" d="M120,0L0,-120" transform='rotate(45)'></path>
    <path class="link-anim blue" d="M120,0L0,-120" transform='rotate(45)' >
 </path>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>

path.link {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
  stroke: black;
}
path.link-anim {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  animation: link-anim 5s linear infinite;
}
path.red {
  stroke: red;
}
path.blue {
  stroke: blue;
}
@keyframes link-anim {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 5 5 100%;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
        stroke-dasharray: 100% 5 5;
    }
}
div {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: I don't care about the angle of the path, I care about the 3 dots that should move forward, but thanks for that :)

Comment: OK I'll take a look

Comment: One thing you can do is make an animated gif which would work

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the path can be in different length and I have multiple paths (that can change) in that SVG, so animated gif will not work :(

Answer (score 0):

a `<path>` has a `d` attribute with `x, y` points in it.

all you have to do is loop over those points and set the current one to a `circle`'s `cx` and `cy`

the points will need to be cleaned before.

have a look at the [Demo](https://codepen.io/orouz/pen/YQzOPR)

Comment: Hi Uzi, thanks for that example. I'm mostly looking for a css solution, but even If I was looking for a javascript one - this will not give the result I was looking for. Please double check the question.

Comment: to achieve the specific result you're after, you will need to do some more work (add 2 circles and keep them sync). the concept is the same though - that's how you move an svg circle along a path. btw, your question, doesn't say you're looking for a css solution. it only shows you've tried css.